# CSS Grid hiding text on mobile (mobile first)

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, grid, media-queries

I am building a navigation bar and using CSS grid.

Here is the html:

```
<nav class="nav">
    <div class="menu">
        <div class="header">
            HEADER
        </div>
    </div>
    <span class="space"></span>
    <div class="breadcrumb">
        <div class="bcrumb">
            Breadcrumbs
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="content">

</div>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    margin:0;
}
.nav {
    height: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    display:grid;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 5px 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: 
    "Menu"
    "Space"
    "Breadcrumb"
}
.content{
  height:1000px;
  background-color:gray;
  margin-top:100px;
}
.menu {
    grid-area: Menu;
    background-color: #333333;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1.5em 80px 1fr auto;
    grid-template-areas: ". . . MenuItems";
}
.menu-items {
    grid-area: MenuItems;
}
.space {
    grid-area: Space;
    background-color: #c20418;
}
.breadcrumb {
    grid-area: Breadcrumb;
    background-color: white;
}
@media only screen and (min-width : 1224px) {
    .menu {
        display:inline-grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1.5em 80px auto 1fr auto auto;
        grid-template-areas: ". . Header . . MenuItems";
        align-content: end;
    }

    .header {
        grid-area: Header;
        color: white;
        font-size: 1.2em;
    }

    .breadcrumb {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1.5em 80px 1fr;
        grid-template-areas: ". . Bcrumb";
    }

    .bcrumb {
        grid-area: Bcrumb;
        align-self: center;
        font-size: 1.2em;
    }
}
```

I have made it with an header text and text place for breadcrumbs that should only be there when on larger screens.

I've made it work by adding:

```
.header, .bcrumb{ 
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

and then set it to visible in the media queries.

**But surely there must be a better way to do this?**

Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fnt6ez0s/12/) with the same code.

Comment: What Css framework are you using?

Comment: @JohannesPiontkowitz none. I am using this [css grid](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7kVeCqQCxlk&t=14s)

Comment: Then using media queries will be the best way of accomplishing this.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the CSS for mobile screens

```
@media all and (max-width: 767px) {
  .header, .bcrumb { 
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}
```

Comment: This answer is not good, since it is a mobile first page.
I have edited my title after reading this answer.

Comment: But this will work only on less than 767px wide screens.Not on larger screens. You can use what size you want instead of 767.

Comment: [media queries and mobile first](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)


**Instead of changing styles when the width gets smaller than 768px, we should change the design when the width gets larger than 768px.**

Comment: Then use visibility:hidden without media queries. It will hide both the elements. And use visibility:visible for larger screens in your queries that you have already for larger screens.

Comment: Then i have to declare where it is visible aswell. Like i wrote in my question, i already know this solution, however i wish to find out if there is another way where i don't have to declare the `visibility` of my `div`'s. 

What i get of CSS Grid is that this should somehow be possible without defining the `visibility`

Comment: display property is the other option. display:none AND display:block

Comment: `display: none;` worked for my `.breadcrumbs` class. 

The problem is it is not possible to apply this on my `.menu` class since it is diplaying an other grid where the `.header` class is not part of.

Comment: If i understand what you're asking, there is no way of handling this without using media queries or javascript.

Comment: Guess you are right.. I just thought it was possible since you can do it the other way around with CSS Grid. 

When you have a `grid-area` and don't add it in a media query `grid-area-template`, then it is not visible.